# Unhide row doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

One worksheet doesn't show the first 15 rows. I tried the followings, neither worked, even in full-screen mode

- Step 1: F5 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) to define &
  select 1:15, set row height to 20 and
  "unhide row", they are still hiding;
- Step 2: Put cursor in A16, then up..
  till A1 (invisible), select entire
  row (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>), hold on <kbd>Shift</kbd>
  key, press <kbd>↓</kbd>, till all 15
  rows selected, set height and unhide
  row, still doesn't work!

How can I get them back?

Comment: Your question does not seem related to programming

Comment: It's formating :-)

Comment: Select all rows, paste them into a new worksheet, all rows show up

Comment: could you maybe post a screenshot of your worksheet with the hidden rows? have you checked if there are any addins/vba-macros active - linke `Wokrsheet_change`? Could you add a screenshot of your VBE with the problematic workbook opended in?

Comment: Click a row number at far left, press ctrl a to select all rows, right click row numbers on left, right click, click "unhide".

Answer (score 23):

Select the *Sort & filter* icon from the home menu bar, uncheck the *Filter* button.

To me, it looks like bug in Excel filters.

Answer (score 6):

I had the issue you were describing and found that the rows were unhidden, but the row height was zero. So, unhide the rows as you describe and then hover over the row symbols on the side (in between the two rows where your rows are hidden) and then click and drag to expand the row height manually.

There's probably a visual basic script to do this that you could code up as well.

Answer (score 3):

Also, be careful that you haven't got a frozen pane.  This can cause all sort of problems.

From View, look under Window and for Freeze Pane, there's an Unfreeze Pane option.

This one drove me nuts for half an hour until I realized what was going on.  Unhide on its own didn't work. Neither did changing row height.  Frozen panes are very subtle.

Answer (score 2):

If you select all the rows and click 'unhide' and they do not show up, then they are filtered and not hidden. Click the Sort & Filter button on the Home tab of the ribbon and then click 'clear'.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Type the first cell reference A1 in the Name Box and press enter.
On the Home tab, click on the Format icon
Choose Hide & Unhide from the dropdown menu then select Unhide Rows.

You should be able to unhide all of the rows inbetween after that.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work either. I tried the following VBA code, not work either:

`
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For i = 1 To 15
        Set rng = Rows(i)
        rng.Locked = False
        rng.RowHeight = 20
        rng.Hidden = False
    Next
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
`

Comment: Tried all the solutions listed in http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformatting/qt/070814unhiderow.htm, none of them works.

Answer (score 1):

I removed my filter from the whole worksheet and everything appeared.  Then I highlighted everything I wanted filtered and re-applied the filter.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but there is a way to get the rows back.

use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

If you can't see a window labelled **Immediate Window** then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get there.

In that window, type (or copy) the following code, adjusting for the rows you want unhidden, and the sheetname

```
for x=1 to 15:sheets("WorkSheetName").range("A"&x).entirerow.rowheight=17:next
```

This sets the height of all 15 rows to a height of *17*, and you can then manipulate them how you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the rows you want unhidden. Double click on the space between the rows in the numbers column, (on the left side) your mouse pointer icon will change from a pointing right symbol to an expansion symbol. The hidden rows will show themselves.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select GOTO (CTRL+G)
2. Select the hidden rows only...  if hidden rows are 3 to 100, then 3:100
3. In the menu bar select Format > Row Height
   The hidden rows should all have a value of "0".
4. Change and set the height of the rows to what you want... ie 15
5. All of the hidden rows should now be visible

Answer (score 0):

If the unhide doesn't work or the unhide option doens't show, you can put the mouse between the column where the diveder is and drag right and you can unhide each column one by one unwarapping it :)

Not ideal if you have many columns hidden there but useful if you have a few.